# Prove that n! is greater than n at a given power

Tags: inequality, factorial

Can someone help me with this demonstration?

$n! \geq n^{log_2 5} $

for $n > 10$

Comment: @agoodguy hey, why you delete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213136/interleaving-string-with-three-or-four-strings this question? I posted an answer there and instead of accept, you removed the question. So, why did I put that effort for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Prove that $n! \ge n^3$ for $n \ge 10$. (It actually holds for $n\ge 6$).

Indeed,
$$
n! = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 2 \cdot 1 > 2n(n-1)(n-2) > n^3 \mbox{ if } n\ge 6
$$

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of two successive factorials is the growing factor $n$, and that of two powers is $(n/(n-1))^p$, which is bounded by the constant $(10/9)^p$ (for $n>10$). Sooner or later the LHS will exceed the RHS.